# How can I create a custom function in PHP for HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, tags

Last time I asked for help in PHP and I got great response. Thanks to all of you for that. Now I am learning and creating website using MVC PHP. I want to ask you that can I create a custom function to use html tags? I am trying to remember that where I saw an example of it. Actually I've seen it before in and open source project.

It was like something this:

```
htmltag(script(src=address, type=javascript))
```

Its output was in html like:

```
<script src="address" type="javascript"></script>
```

So can I create something like this? I am trying to do this way:

```
public function script($var1, $var2){
    $var1 = array(
                'type'=>'',
                'charset' => '',
                'src' => ''
            );
    $var2 = false;
    print("<script $var1>$var2</script>");
    }
```

So can anyone guide me with this? Do I need to create class first? I will be waiting for your reply friends.

Comment: you cannot dump an array into a string like that. You're going to end up with `<script Array></script>`.

Comment: so any suggestion? can I create something like that? Or I should use echo <script></script> ?

Comment: Not to be harsh, but you're demonstrating a huge lack of knowledge in very basic PHP.  You might get a workable answer to this question, but it would do you the most good to spend (a lot) more time learning about PHP basics before you try to roll your own MVC application.

Comment: I know It will take a lot time. Because I am learning by myself. Day by day, creating something new.

Comment: Take a look at the [DOMElement](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) class in PHP, with some massaging, its the most correct way of achieving what you want.

Comment: Thanx @phpisuber01. I looked at it and looks good and helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript** works with DOM, [see the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM)

```
function htmltag(name,atts) {
    var tag = document.createElement(name);
    for(var i in atts) tag.setAttribute(i, atts[i]);
    return tag;
}

var img = htmltag("img", {
    src: "https://kevcom.com/images/linux/linux.logo.2gp.jpg",
    alt: "linux logo"
});

document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Note that `img` here is object (XML Node), not just plain text, so you can attach events on it etc. If you want to extract just the plain html code from it, use `img.outerHTML`. Test it on [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzSHh/).

Note: `print` is the equivalent of Ctrl+P in the browser :-) it is not the print equivalent in PHP.

In **PHP** you can use [DOM::createElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and other methods from DOM which are quite similar to those from javascript. Personaly I prefer something more simple:

```
function tag($name,$atts="",$content="") {
    $str_atts = "";
    if(is_array($atts)) {
    foreach($atts as $key=>$val) if(!($val===null || $val===false)) $str_atts.= " $key=\"$val\"";
  } else $str_atts = " ".preg_replace("/=(?!\")(\S+)/m","=\"\\1\"",$atts);
    if($name=="img" && !strpos($str_atts,"alt=")) $str_atts.= " alt=\"\"";
    if(in_array($name,array("input","img","col","br","hr","meta"))) $name.= "/";
    if(substr($name,-1)=="/") { $name = substr($name,0,-1); return "<{$name}{$str_atts}/>"; }
    else return "<{$name}{$str_atts}>$content</$name>";
}
```

Examples

```
  echo tag("p","class=foo id=bar1","hello");
  echo tag("p",'class="foo" id="bar2"',"hey");
  echo tag("p",array("class"=>"foo","id"=>"bar3"),"heya");
  echo tag("img","src=https://kevcom.com/images/linux/linux.logo.2gp.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But can you guide me with PHP if possible? I will use this too. :D